# How to get the value of the xml object with @attribute key=>value option in php

Tags: javascript, php, xml

[image]

The question his how to select the fourth value of node with a @attribute=key=>value and output the "Bosch Osterreich" value from the:

```
<value lc="AT">Bosch Osterreich<value>
```

Please don't hard code the values provide a function.

Comment: Did you just copy this question from your homework?

Comment: No I did not, i was wondering how to output that if someone new.

Comment: Well, have a look at [simpleXML](http://php.net/simplexml) for reading, parsing and accessing xml documents within PHP.

Comment: I have one function that loads them like $object=simple_load_string(""); than i loop through the values with foreach($object->values as $value){$value->here i don't  want to write it like $value[4] but something like $value->attributes()->["lc'']=["AT"] and print -> Bosch Osterreich }

Answer (score 0):

The final answer was to create a for loop outside foreach loop and then creating a key=>value option and then if(value equals to Key=>Value)
{echo print the exact output of that value you want}.
Below you have two examples that print out the data you want.

```
            //First Example

            for($i=0;$i<count($job->officeCountry->values->value);$i++)   
            {
                foreach ($job->officeCountry->values->value[$i]->attributes() as $a => $b) {
                if ($a . '=' . $b == "lc" . '=' . 'AT') {

                    echo $state = $b;
                }
              }
            }

        //Second Example

        for($i=0;$i<count($job->offices->office->values->value);$i++) 
        {
            if($job->offices->office->values->value[$i]->attributes()->lc=="AT")
            {
                echo $city=$job->offices->office->values->value[$i];
            }
        }
```